# $search and $expand operator does not work in graph api users

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using graph api to get users and groups information,
but looks it does not work, can anyone help me?

my query uri:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$search="displayname:user"&$count=true&$top=250&$expand=transitiveMemberOf($select=displayname)
```

and the error message:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
    "message": "Request with $search query parameter only works through MSGraph with a special request header: 'ConsistencyLevel: eventual'",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2022-01-14T11:06:50",
        "request-id": "e57ce8c4-f1bc-4b32-8559-1fac5c133b9d",
        "client-request-id": "c85557de-6e80-10b6-7c68-d84334181dd0"
    }
}
```

}

and i added the request header[ConsistencyLevel: eventual] nothing changed.

Comment: I am having the same issue, I'd love to see if anyone knows the answer. To clarify, removing $expand parameter would let the query run properly.

Comment: Did you get any update on this ticket?

Answer (score 0):

> $expand is not currently supported with advanced queries.

[image]

Adding request header `ConsistencyLevel:eventual` and removing `&$expand=transitiveMemberOf($select=displayname)`

related documents:

troubleshooting your [error message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries#error-handling-for-advanced-queries-on-directory-objects)

[expand parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#expand-parameter)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?view=graph-rest-1.0) and github [issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/15517#issuecomment-1017019278), unfortunately `$search` (requiring the advanced query parameters) doesn't support `$expand`.